# How to keep current month on top of list, when using ng-repeat in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have list of holidays and I am using ng-repeat to show this on html.
it is working fine but I need current month's holidays(or upcoming) on top of list how to do that.... help me

My list is

```
$scope.holidaylist =
[
 {
  "lineId":0,
  "holidayMasterId":0,
  "holidayName":"NewYear",
  "startDate":"2016-01-01T00:00:00",
  "endDate":"2016-01-01T00:00:00",
  "startDay":"Friday"
  },
  {
  "lineId":0,
  "holidayMasterId":0,
  "holidayName":"Sankranthi",
  "startDate":"2016-01-15T00:00:00",
  "endDate":"2016-01-15T00:00:00",
  "startDay":"Friday"
  },
  {
  "lineId":0,
  "holidayMasterId":0,
  "holidayName":"Ugadi",
  "startDate":"2016-04-04T00:00:00",
  "endDate":"2016-04-04T00:00:00",
  "startDay":"Monday"
  },
  {
  "lineId":0,
  "holidayMasterId":0,
  "holidayName":"Ugadi",
  "startDate":"2016-04-05T00:00:00",
  "endDate":"2016-04-05T00:00:00",
  "startDay":"Tuesday"
  },
  {
  "lineId":0,
  "holidayMasterId":0,
  "holidayName":"Ugadi",
  "startDate":"2016-04-06T00:00:00",
  "endDate":"2016-04-06T00:00:00",
  "startDay":"Wednesday"
  },
  {
  "lineId":0,
  "holidayMasterId":0,
  "holidayName":"Ugadi",
  "startDate":"2016-04-07T00:00:00",
  "endDate":"2016-04-07T00:00:00",
  "startDay":"Thursday"
  },
  {
  "lineId":0,
  "holidayMasterId":0,
  "holidayName":"Ugadi",
  "startDate":"2016-04-08T00:00:00",
  "endDate":"2016-04-08T00:00:00",
  "startDay":"Friday"
  }
];
```

this is my markup

```
                <li ng-if="holidaylist!=null" class="order-item" ng-repeat="holiday in holidaylist">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8 item-left">
                            <div class="item-booker">{{holiday.holidayName}}</div>
                            <div class="item-time">
                                <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                                <span>{{holiday.startDate | date:'dd-MM-yyyy'}}</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 item-right">
                            <div class="item-price">
                                <span class="price">{{holiday.startDay}}</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
```

Comment: Not too familiar with angularJS yet. But isn't the right approach something like this? {{ orderBy_expression | orderBy : expression : reverse}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `orderBy: 'startDate':true` to sort the holidays.
The reverse argument is a boolean value.

```
<li ng-if="holidaylist!=null" class="order-item" ng-repeat="holiday in holidaylist | orderBy: 'startDate':true">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8 item-left">
                            <div class="item-booker">{{holiday.holidayName}}</div>
                            <div class="item-time">
                                <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                                <span>{{holiday.startDate | date:'dd-MM-yyyy'}}</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 item-right">
                            <div class="item-price">
                                <span class="price">{{holiday.startDay}}</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
```

Comment: Appreciate your effort but it not the right way.
if you are familiar with angularjs then would know, it would be undefined where you are telling to use it.
and BTW it is already sorted by date in the list. if you observed.

Comment: Answer accepted my lord..you saved my time.
thanks a lot